# Custom HTTP response headers on internal IdentityServer4 endpoints

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I've been trying to add some custom HTTP response headers to the built-in IdentityServer endpoints like */connect/checksession* with global filter approach depicted in the code snippet below (taken from *Startup.cs* *ConfigureServices* method):

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
   options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
   options.Filters.Add(typeof(SecurityHeadersAttribute));
});
```

While the headers appear just fine on custom MVC endpoints like */AccountSelect* and */Login* the internal IdentityServer endpoints seem to ignore those altogether.

I was thinking whether the order of the registration in the startup overrides the global filters. In my case the code below is executed after *AddMvc*

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
   //code omitted for brevity
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add your own middleware step in the request pipeline that will execute for every incoming request to your IdentityServer application.

Just add this code in Startup.Configure:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("MyMagic", "Header");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
    await next();
});
```